# How to await Messages from DM?

Tags: discord.js

How to await Messages from member in Private Messages?

I tried this but it is not working

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content === prefix + "apply"){

      await message.author.send("Working !");
      await message.channel.awaitMessages(Response => message.content, {
        max: 1,
        time: 50000
      })
      .then((collected) => {
        if(collected.first().content === "cancel") return message.reply("Canceled");
        message.author.send("Done !");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        message.author.send("Timeout");
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there an error or does it not do anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you are mixing techniques here. Using `await` means you don't have to do a `.then()` It's also unclear why you are doing an await on a response from a remote user (timing out after 50s)?

Answer (score 1):

`message.channel` is still the Channel where apply was run, so use:

```
const msg = await message.author.send('Working !');
const filter = collected => collected.author.id === message.author.id;
const collected = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 50000,
}).catch(() => {
    message.author.send('Timeout');
});

if(collected.first().content === 'cancel') return message.reply('Canceled');
message.author.send('Done !');
```

Comment: Any Error ? Also make sure to replace everything